# Foreach loop not displaying content properly

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node.js and its framework express to create a movie image gallery. A foreach loop is used to display data onto the page. The image gallery should display 4 images across in each row. For some apparent reason, the layout grid is broken and images are being duplicated when displayed on page. How can I create a grid layout for my image gallery with no duplicated data?

index.ejs

```
<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row-image">
    <% movies.forEach(function(movies) { %>
  <div class="column">
      <a href="/movies/<%=movies._id %>"><img src="<%= movies.image %>" style="width:100%"></a>
        <div class="desc">
            <a href="/movies/<%=movies._id %>"><%= movies.name %></a>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <a href="/movies/<%=movies._id %>"><img src="<%= movies.image %>" style="width:100%"></a>
        <div class="desc"><a href="/movies/<%=movies._id %>"><%= movies.name %></a></div>
  </div>  
</div>
<% } ); %>
```

main.css

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }




 .row-image {
   display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
   display: flex;
   -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   padding: 0 14px;
 }

 /* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
 .column {
   -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
   flex: 25%;
   max-width: 25%;
   padding: 0 4px 20px;  
 }

 .column img {
   margin-top: 8px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 9px;
 }




 .desc a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #b3b3b3;
 }

 /* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   .column {
     -ms-flex: 50%;
     flex: 50%;
     max-width: 50%;
   }
 }

 /* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .column {
     -ms-flex: 100%;
     flex: 100%;
     max-width: 50%;
   }
 }
```

Comment: It looks to me that you have the same fragment of HTML twice. Review you HTML.

Comment: The closing `<% } ); %>` should go before the last `</div>`